# Translate product's informations ( descriptions, short description, title,..)

Tags: magento-1.9, product, product-attribute, store-view, localisation

How I can translate product's informations (descriptions, short description, title, ...) in a lot of languages (English, French, German, ...) without creating the product multiple times for each language?

Can I do that just with store view in Magento?

Answer (score 1):

In Magento you create *store views* (System > Store Management) for different languages. Then you can change most product attributes for each store view separately (or use the default value if you choose not to).

Switch the store view for which you want to edit the attributes at the top left:

[image: example screenshot]

Comment: @ fschmengler thank you for your reply. Please, the product's data for each store view are stored in "catalog_product_entity_text", but what about data category?

Comment: For categories the same tables exist

Comment: @ fschmengler Please, how i can manage the categories of product, because, the same product can have different category according to each seller